# toPandas() work from Jupyter iPython Notebook but fails on submit - AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, pandas, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a program that:
 1. reads some data
 2. perform some operations
 3. Saves a csv file
 4. Transport that file to FTP

I am using Amazon EMR cluster and PySpark to accomplish this task.

For step 4, I need to save the CSV on the local storage and not on HDFS. For this purpose, I convert the Spark Dataframe to Pandas dataframe.

a snippet could be:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, LongType, StringType
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
from time import time
import timeit
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import random as rand
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations, permutations
from collections import defaultdict
from ftplib import FTP
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Recommendation").set('spark.driver.memory', '8G').set('spark.executor.memory', '4G')
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


readRdd = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').load('s3n://my-bucket/myfile' + path)

df = readRdd.toPandas() # <---------- PROBLEM
print('toPandas() completed')

df.to_csv('./myFile')
```

The problem is:

when I run this code from Jpyter iPython notebook on the same cluster, it works like a charm. But when I run this code using Spark Submit, or add it as a step to EMR, the code fails on the following line:

```
df = readRdd.toPandas()
```

'toPandas() completed' is never printed

In the spark job monitor, I can see that the toPandas() method gets executed but right after that I get the error.

```
16/10/10 13:17:47 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 1 executor(s).
16/10/10 13:17:47 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:17:47 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:17:47 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1462.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 10624) in 2089 ms on ip-172-31-38-70.eu-west-1.compute.internal (1515/1516)
16/10/10 13:17:47 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1485.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 10647) in 2059 ms on ip-172-31-38-70.eu-west-1.compute.internal (1516/1516)
16/10/10 13:17:47 INFO YarnClusterScheduler: Removed TaskSet 17.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/10/10 13:17:47 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 17 (toPandas at 20161007_RecPipeline.py:182) finished in 12.609 s
16/10/10 13:17:47 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 4 finished: toPandas at 20161007_RecPipeline.py:182, took 14.646644 s
16/10/10 13:17:47 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 0 executor(s).
16/10/10 13:17:47 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:17:47 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:17:50 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:17:50 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:17:53 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:17:53 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:17:56 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:17:56 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:17:59 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:17:59 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:18:02 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:18:02 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:18:05 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:18:05 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:18:08 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:18:08 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:18:11 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:18:11 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:18:14 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:18:14 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:18:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:18:17 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:18:20 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:18:20 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:18:23 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:18:23 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:18:26 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:18:26 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:18:29 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:18:29 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:18:32 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:18:32 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:18:35 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/10/10 13:18:35 WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
16/10/10 13:18:36 ERROR ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://172.31.37.28:45777
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO YarnClusterSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO YarnClusterSchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/10/10 13:18:36 ERROR PythonRDD: Error while sending iterator
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(PythonRDD.scala:648)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:648)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:648)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1250)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$2.run(PythonRDD.scala:649)
16/10/10 13:18:36 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User application exited with status 143
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 143, (reason: User application exited with status 143)
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt3/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1476100925559_0002/spark-eab43d4e-7201-4bcb-8ee7-0e7b546e8fd8
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1476100925559_0002/spark-1d88398f-ecd5-4d94-a42a-a406b3d566af/pyspark-34bec23c-a686-475d-85c9-9e9228b23239
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1476100925559_0002/spark-1d88398f-ecd5-4d94-a42a-a406b3d566af
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt3/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1476100925559_0002/container_1476100925559_0002_01_000001/tmp/spark-96cdee47-e3f3-45f4-8bc7-0df5928ef53c
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt2/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1476100925559_0002/spark-f6821ea1-6f37-4cc6-8bba-049ac0215786
16/10/10 13:18:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1476100925559_0002/spark-1827cae8-8a60-4b29-a4e5-368a8e1856fd
```

My cluster configuration looks like:

```
spark-defaults  spark.driver.maxResultSize  8G
spark-defaults  spark.driver.memory 8G
spark-defaults  spark.executor.memory   4G
```

The Spark Submit command looks like:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster s3://my-bucket/myPython.py
```

This is killing me! Someone please give me any pointers to what direction I may look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the problem:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster s3://my-bucket/myPython.py
```

In the above command, the deploy mode is set to cluster which means a node will be chosen out of the core nodes to run the driver program. Since the allowed driver memory is 8G and the core nodes were smaller physical instances, they would always run out of required memory.

The solution was to deploy in client mode where the driver would always run on the master node  (a bigger physical instance with more resources in my case) would not run out of required memory for the whole process.

Since it was a dedicated cluster, this solution worked in my case.

In case of a shared cluster where deploy mode must be cluster, using bigger instances should work.